# How to remove cloth pattern and change color but keep shadows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

In the passport image, using Photoshop, I want to change the suit color to black, remove the shirt pattern and change the shirt color to white but I want to keep the shadows. I tried to change the suit's color by creating a new layer and making its blending mode to Multiply with new color but got something dark greenish, could not get pure black. But I have no idea how I can remove the shirt's pattern and change the color to white. I could simply use an eraser but the shadows will be gone too obviously.

[image: image to be edited]

Comment: I'd rather take a photo with a white shirt and paste it in. I'm not sure it will be possible to remove the shirt's texture, the pattern blends in too much with the shadows.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Why don't you try to desaturate the image? And then change the levels

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.